# MKMapview crash after start second time iOS8

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have got this error and crash.

```
ERROR /SourceCache/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-992.19/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1719: InfoLog SimpleGrid:
ERROR /SourceCache/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-992.19/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1720: ERROR: OpenGL ES requires exactly one vertex and one fragment shader to validly link.
```

It is when I start MKMapView second time.

It is only on iPad iOS8.

I am using cocos2d in my project.

Any idea?